# Simulate drag with spectron

Tags: javascript, electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I want to simulate a drag within an element using spectron/electron.
I tried 2 ways:

```
await client.moveToObject(selector, fromX, fromY);
await client.buttonDown(0);
await client.moveToObject(selector, toX, toY);
await client.buttonUp(0);
```

and

```
await webContents.sendInputEvent({
  type: "mouseMove",
  x: fromX,
  y: fromY
});
await webContents.sendInputEvent({
  type: "mouseDown",
  button: "left",
  x: fromX,
  y: fromY
});
await webContents.sendInputEvent({
  type: "mouseMove",
  button: "left",
  x: toX,
  y: toY
});
await webContents.sendInputEvent({
  type: "mouseUp",
  button: "left",
  x: toX,
  y: toY
});
```

I also tried plenty different versions/combinations of the above (including e.g. movementX & movementY). I can't use the actions api (my driver does not implement it yet).

With all my approaches, nothing at all happens (no errors neither). Is there a way to implement drag (not drag&drop, it's just within one element)?

Comment: You might miss the "clickCount" field when using sendInputEvent.

Comment: @hiitiger can you elaborate? What does clickCount mean in this context?

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentssendinputeventevent

webContents.sendInputEvent({
  type: "mouseDown",
  button: "left",
  x: fromX,
  y: fromY,
  clickCount: 1
});

and I don't think sendInputEvent return a promise so don't use await on it.

Comment: This and many variations of it don't help. sendInputEvent does indeed return a promise (I know the typing says otherwise, but console.log tells the truth).